# Why is ~null === -1?

Tags: javascript

A questions that stumped me on [this JavaScript test](http://asserttrue.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/are-you-javascript-guru-try-this-test.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+hnycombinator+%28HN+-+hnycombinator%29) was that `~null` evaluates to `-1`.

Why does `~null` evaluate to `-1`?

Comment: The `tilde` is a [**Bitwise NOT Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_(Bitwise_NOT)) - As seen in the documentation `Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1). For example, ~5 yields -6.` - Therefore `null/undefined` which is turned into `0` is `-(0+1)` resulting in `-1`

Comment: Your assertion is not necessarily true, it depends on the architecture of a microprocessor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `~` is a numeric operator, so it casts `null` to `0` first:

```
> ~0
-1
```

It would be equivalent to this expression:

```
~(+null)
```

Likewise:

```
> ~[]
-1
> ~{}
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `~` is a bitwise `NOT` operator. That means it flips all the bits in the number representation. `0010 1010` becomes `1101 0101`.

As a consequence of computers using 2's complement for storing numbers, this equality holds:

```
~number == -number - 1
```

As can be shown from my previous example:

`0010 1010` (this represents number `42`)

`1101 0101` (this represents number `-43`)

Now, because `~` is an operator that operates on numbers, its **argument gets cast to a number** first. Since `null` gets cast to a `0`, you get `-1` as a result (according the above equation).